# How to model life-events such as "married" and "bought house" in salesforce

Tags: tasks, event

I'm pretty new to Salesforce and therefore have not yet grasped the data model and the intended use for specific standard objects.

I have to register life-events such as "married" or "bought a house" in salesforce. These events are of cause bound to a person, which in my case is a combination of an account and a contact.

The obvious candidate would be to use the Event object, but reading about it in the documentation, an Event describes a calendar event to which there are invitees and it is also ment to have a given duration. This is not quite what I was looking for.

Are there any other objects that would be more suited for this type of data, or should I go custom and create a custom object to do the job?

Also, can I relate this life-event to multiple accounts? And preferably without creating a custom relationship between the life-event and the accounts.

Comment: It really comes down to what data/fields that you want to set to those two events. Adding to Blair's input,  No you cannot have multiple Accounts related to one custom 'event' object even with relationship because the Standard objects cannot be a child object to a parent. You need to have a junction object to satisfy this use-case. I will let the expertise to have more insights on this one.

Answer (score 2):

A custom object would probably be best so that you can capture information specific to the life event. If different information needs to be captured for each type of life event, then you would want to create page layouts on that object for each type of life event and link those page layouts to record types. The record types would be named after the life event. Or you could just have one page layout and have the user select what type of life event it is using a picklist field.